# Batch Unzip, Rename zip contents to original zip file name, Rezip

Tags: batch-file

I found this script here that works well (thanks MC ND!). However, I dont want to retain the original name that was in the zip file. Please see below:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for %%z in (*.zip) do (
        if not exist "%%~nz" md "%%~nz"
        7za e -o"%%~nz" "%%~fz"
        for %%f in ("%%~nz\*") do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nz - %%~nxf"
    )
```

For each zip file, if a folder with the same name does not exist, create it. Extract the zip file into the new folder. For each file inside the folder, rename the file to the name of the zip **followed by the original name of the file.**

I would like to remove the bold part from the script. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the last 'for' line that handles the individual file renaming.

Comment: Thank you for your reply however I would like to rename the files that are extracted. I just dont want the original extracted names to follow the new renamed file. For example:

Comment: the original zip file is  **1234-1 - Win, Mac.zip** but the extracted contents are 1 - win.ccd and 2 - mac.exe. I would like the extracted contents to be **1234-1 - Win, Mac.ccd** and **1234-1 - Win, Mac.exe** . The script above does this but _also_ adds the original content name to the extracted files, which I dont want. Sorry if I wasnt clear with my request.

Comment: **Still hoping for some help on this... thanks. 400+ files to rename.

Comment: for %%f in ("%%~nz\*") do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nz%%~xf"

Comment: Keep in mind that if your contents are win.ccd and win1.ccd, you will have different error.

Comment: I am sorry but this did not work. Thank you for your efforts.